# The project is using an incompatible version (AGP 7.3.0-alpha07) of the Android Gradle plugin

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to use architecture project (todo list) but get this error when i want to run project

The project is using an incompatible version (AGP 7.3.0-alpha07) of the Android Gradle plugin. Latest supported version is AGP 7.2.1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Update to the latest version of Android Studio i.e. Dolphin and your problem will be resolved

Comment: The same here with me.

Comment: In my case it's not a good variant because a project compiles in Chipmunk and doesn't compile in Dolphin.

Comment: Upgraded to Dolphin and still getting the error

Comment: Thanks. Android Studio gives a link, "[See Android Studio & AGP compatibility options](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#android_gradle_plugin_and_android_studio_compatibility)", which shows a table with AS and plugin versions. So the solution is to update to a specific version of AS or downgrade to a plugin version that the studio supports. Or using gradle via command line...

Answer (score 99):

Try either to upgrade Android Studio or change AGP version to the stable version like for example `7.2.1` in the project's `build.gradle` file and sync the project:

```
buildscript {
    //...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'

        // ...
    }
}
```

You can refer to this [table](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle), that lists which version of **Gradle** is required for each version of the **Android Gradle plugin**.

Or this [table](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#android_gradle_plugin_and_android_studio_compatibility) that lists which version of the **Android Gradle plugin** is required for each version of **Android Studio**.

Comment: Check out Fahime's answer.  While the accepted answer works, it is potentially problematic.  A full upgrade, as Fahime recommends, might not be the best choice for your case, but there might be some middle ground that can work for you.  

Thanks to Sergio for a solution that also works.

Comment: I'm already using com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1 and I still get the error

Comment: @Hugo try to upgrade Android Studio.

Comment: @Sergio I'm already on the latest version

Answer (score 48):

Instead of downgrading your AGP version in the accepted answer, you can update your android studio.

Answer (score 23):

go to  `File > Settings` and Update Android Studio

[image: file menu]
[image: update]

Comment: Help > Check for updates...

Answer (score 9):

```kotlin
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}
```

In plugins change the version according to other projects use in your android studio check that and change according to them it will work.

Comment: i tried it from developers site but did'nt work ..and trying it from seeing other Android projects and it worked thanks... : )

Answer (score 2):

**Update your Android Studio to the latest Android Studio (Dolphin version) version.**

Answer (score 2):

`dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1' }`

In the project grade file just change this from 7.4.2 or other newer version to whatever version you want..
Just sync the gradle file.
And
BOOM ... it will work ... Try again install it.

Answer (score 2):

In Help -> Check for updates you can find it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlinVersion = '1.6.10'
ext.navigationVersion = '2.4.2'
ext.ktlintVersion = '0.44.0'
ext.hiltVersion = '2.42'

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigationVersion"
    classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hiltVersion"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Setting the versions in the top-level build.gradle as seen above, worked for me.

It is important to change the kotlinVersion as well!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution worked for above issue for me :**

while using KMP I was prompted to upgrade my AGP to version 8.3.0, after which I started getting the exact same error as the author of this post. I was able to resolve this issue, to do so follow the following steps:

1. switch to the "Project" foreground instead of Android
   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaHWa.png)
2. Navigate to the gradle directory
3. Edit the "libs.versions.toml" file by changing the value of the "agp" variable to the one you want, in my case 8.2.0.
   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBhv7.png)
4. Sync gradle project.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error when i updated android studio the error is gone and all things are working proper, ***So You Just Update Your Android Studio.***
In Mac keyboard cmd + , press -> Apprearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Updates -> Check for Updates -> Update Now

Answer (score -1):

check your android studio version, here is corresponding table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7Ybb.png)